# Using LinkGenerator outside of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 controller I have the following:

```
var url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, action: "GetContentByFileId", values: new { FileId = 1 });
```

I injected LinkGenerator in the Controller ...

Now I need generate the url in a class which is not a controller so I tried:

```
var url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(action: "GetContentByFileId", controller: "FileController", values: new { FileId = 1 });
```

However, I get the message saying I need more arguments. Why?

What is the correct way to use LinkGenerator outside of a Controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If not using the [`GetUriByAction`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/ControllerLinkGeneratorExtensions.cs#L149) overload that requires `HttpContext` then you have to provide **all** the required arguments of the other

```
public static string GetUriByAction(
        this LinkGenerator generator,
        string action,
        string controller,
        object values,
        string scheme,
        HostString host,
        PathString pathBase = default,
        FragmentString fragment = default,
        LinkOptions options = default)
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/ControllerLinkGeneratorExtensions.cs#L208)

Which in your example would be the `scheme` and `host`.

As an alternative you can also consider injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` so you have access to `HttpContext` outside of controller and be able to make the call just like how you did when invoked from within the controller.

```
var url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(_accessor.HttpContext, 
    action: "GetContentByFileId", 
    values: new { FileId = 1 }
);
```

Comment: Links are broken :/

Comment: @zola25 updated the links to where the source code were moved to.

Comment: @zola25 thank you for the heads up on the broken links.

Comment: Thanks. I was just told by the MS Blazor team that I should use LinkGenerator because there is no HttpContext in Blazor and was trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution and it works fine for me.

First: Create your custom class service that contains IHttpContextAccessor as a constructor parameter.
Through IHttpContextAccessor you can get LinkGenerator service.

```
public class MyCustomClassService
{
    LinkGenerator _LinkGenerator;
    public MyCustomClassService(IHttpContextAccessor haccess)
    {
        _LinkGenerator = haccess.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<LinkGenerator>();
    }

    public LinkGenerator LinkGenerator
    {
        get
        {
            return _LinkGenerator;
        }
    }

}
```

Then: You need to register MyCustomClassService into Startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<MyCustomClassService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the accepted answer?

Comment: Just wanted to put a solution with more implementation details for more clarification.